# Слова мужского рода

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, стилистика, согласование

В "Поурочных разработках по русскому языку 6 кл." читаю:

> Эти строки написал**а** замечательн**ый** автор детских книг А. Барто.

В правилах читаю:

> В журнале "Знамя" появился нов**ый** автор Петрова.

Мне не понятно, в какой форме нужно писать глагол-сказуемое (если он находится перед сущ.) при существительном мужского рода, которое может обозначать как лицо мужского, так и женского пола. Все понятно, если сказуемое находится после существительного, а вот если перед ним? Везде по-разному пишут: в первом примере согласуют со словами *Агния Барто* (женщина), во втором — со словом *автор* (муж.р). А как правильно?

Какое слово будет подлежащим: *автор* или *Агния*; *автор* или *Петрова*? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, откуда вы взяли второй пример, но он есть в хорошей [статье](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89) Грамоты.ру как раз о ваших трудностях:

> Сказуемое в книжно-письменных стилях (особенно в строгой официально-деловой речи) ставится **в форме мужского рода**: 1) при отсутствии собственного имени; 2) если **сказуемое предшествует** сочетанию «рассматриваемое слово + собственное имя»: *Диссертант изложил интересные наблюдения. Уже известный читателям автор предложил новую статью. Увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Н. Петрова*.

То есть в вашем примере из методички допущена стилистическая ошибка: глагол *написала* в строгой письменной речи должен быть в форме м. р.

*А. Барто* — подлежащее, *написал(а)* — сказуемое, *автор* — приложение.
Приложением является нарицательное существительное, если оно сочетается с фамилией или именем собственным (*майор* Петров, *дворник* Ануфрий).

---

> Доверительно спросил**а** санинспектор Фрося *(П. Павленко)*.

Действительно в "Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" Д. Розенталя приведен этот пример, где сказуемое согласуется в женском роде, а также правило:

> При сочетании нарицательного существительного с собственным именем лица в роли подлежащего выступает последнее, и сказуемое согласуется с ним.

В статье Грамоты.ру (см. выше) даны рекомендации, согласно которым в строгой литературной норме должно быть:

> Доверительно спросил**_** санинспектор Фрося.

Во-первых, эти различия можно обосновать тем, что согласование с женским родом свойственно разговорному стилю, который, вполне возможно, использовал Петр Павленко в своем произведении.
Во-вторых, автор мог подчеркивать, что речь идет именно о женщине.

На мой взгляд, в статье Грамоты.ру приведены более точные и понятные рекомендации, нежели в справочнике Розенталя. Поэтому при объяснении правил согласования сказуемого в подобных случаях я бы придерживался именно нее.

Приведу также цитату из "Словаря грамматических трудностей" Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН:

> В настоящее время сочетания с "самостоятельным женским родом глагола"
>   (по терм. А. М. Пешковского) в устной речи стали правилом: *врач
>   посоветовала, кладовщик написала,* наш *главбух сказала, секретарь
>   написала* правильно...
>   <...>
>   В письменной разновидности литературного языка сочетания типа *сказала мастер спорта*, собравшихся
>   *приветствовала директор школы* иногда придают стилю разговорную окраску. Однако благодаря достаточно широкому употреблению подобных
>   конструкций они не воспринимаются как непривычные — эти сочетания
>   прочно вошли в обиход литературной речи.

Так, в принципе, оба варианта (*спросил* и *спросила*) могут иметь место в грамотной речи.

Comment: Значит, грамматическая основа в первом предложении: Написал Агния Барто, а как это объяснить ученику 6-го класса, ведь они еще не знают о приложении и не смогут понят мужской род глагола-сказуемого при подлежащем женского рода?

Comment: @Верьясова действительно интересная задача... а вам нужно сохранить именно эту форму предложения? Просто немного изменить: *Эти строки написала Агния Барто -- (,) замечательный автор детских книг* -- и нет проблем.

Comment: Да просто хочется знать, как надо правильно писать. В разных правилах и методичках какое-то противоречие. Где же золотая середина?

Comment: Даже у Розенталя пример: Доверительно спросила санинспектор Фрося, т.е опять жен. род , что противоречит Грамоте.ру

Comment: @Верьясова ответ дополнил. Вкратце так: определение в строгой письменной речи должно быть в м. р., согласование сказуемого лучше оставлять также в м. р., однако смысловое (в ж. р.) тоже возможно.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Эти строки написал замечательный автор детских книг А. Барто.

Все знают, что А. Барто — это Агния Барто? А даже если знают, то предложение, в котором  нет никаких намеков на то, что автором является женщина, звучит немного странно. Поэтому используем сказуемое в форме ж. рода: Эти строки **написала** //замечательный автор детских книг //**А. Барто**.

**Обоснование.** Из правил на Грамоте.ру следует: сказуемое может быть поставлено в женском роде, если его форма является **единственным показателем того, что речь идет о женщине, а пишущему важно это подчеркнуть**.

2) А вот со вторым предложением всё нормально: В журнале "Знамя" **появился новый автор //Петрова.**

Собственно говоря, смысл этого правила заключается в том, чтобы обеспечить по возможности плавный и незаметный переход от мужского рода профессии к женскому роду лица, и это касается как определения, так и сказуемого.

Comment: Но это обоснование больше относится к глаголу-сказуемому, которое находится после существ-го, а меня интересует позиция перед подлежащим?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП: переход от одного рода к другому должен быть по возможности единственным, например: В журнале "Знамя" появился новый автор //Петрова. Новый автор //Петрова появилась в журнале "Знамя".

Answer (score 1):

Что там за разборки для шестого класс - не знаю.

Общий принцип таков. Если логическое ударение падает на "автор", то сказуемое идет в мужском роде. Если на Барто/Петрову и/или пол автора по каким-то причинам важен (ну помимо того, что его-де не все знают, это как раз не самое важное), то - в женском.

Случаи, когда пол автора однозначно восстанавливаются по глаголу, конечно могут быть учтены в общем правиле, но императивного влияния на выбор формы не имеют.

Думаю, что в рассматриваемых случаях объяснение вполне можно найти в принципе логического ударения.